# error subsetting data frame for plot purposes in R

Tags: r, subset, histogram

I have a data frame which I can not reproduce and with the columns [col1,col2,...] being  numeric values.
When I try to plot one of the columns:

```
hist(df[,"col1"])
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in hist.default(df[, var]) : 'x' must be numeric*
```

But I can plot it when subsetting the data frame like this:

```
hist(df$col1]
```

This is not happening when plotting a boxplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly probably your `df` is not dataframe but a tibble.

When you subset a dataframe with one-colum you get a vector back.

```
mtcars[, 'mpg']
[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
[17] 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

This works fine with `hist` :

```
hist(mtcars[,"mpg"])
```

which is same as doing

```
hist(mtcars$mpg)
```

But if you have a tibble, subsetting tibble by one-column returns a tibble back.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(mtcars)
df[,"mpg"]

# A tibble: 32 x 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1  21  
# 2  21  
# 3  22.8
# 4  21.4
# 5  18.7
# 6  18.1
# 7  14.3
# 8  24.4
# 9  22.8
#10  19.2
# … with 22 more rows
```

So you get the error :

```
hist(df[,"mpg"])
```

> Error in hist.default(df[, "mpg"]) : 'x' must be numeric

In which case you should use `[[` to get a vector/

```
hist(df[["mpg"]])
```

Comment: > class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: it gave me this error using double brackets [[]]: Error: Subscript can't be missing for tibbles in `[[`.

Comment: but it worked fine converting the dataframe back to a data frame. Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `tibble`, we can also use `$`

```
hist(df$mpg)
```